# In AngularJS, after clicking a button, how to retrieve one of the two Json files and put it in $scope variable?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, web

For example,

There two JSON files:

Json file #1: `[{colorname:blue},{colorname:blue}]`

Json file #2: `[{colorname:red},{colorname:red}]`

In controller, there is a variable `$scope.color`

In html, there are two buttons, one is called "colorblue". the other one is called "colorred".

What I want to do is: When clicking button "colorblue", the `$scope.color` variable equals to Json file #1; When clicking button "colorred", the `$scope.color` variable equals to Json file #2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a function to the button click event. This function will be called in the `$scope` :

```js
function Main($scope) {
  var file1 = [{
    colorname: "blue"
  }, {
    colorname: "blue"
  }];
  var file2 = [{
    colorname: "red"
  }, {
    colorname: "red"
  }];
  $scope.color  = null;
  $scope.file = function(a) {
    switch (a) {
      case 1:
        $scope.color  = file1;
        break;
      case 2:
        $scope.color  = file2;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-controller="Main">
  <button ng-click="file(1)">colorblue</button>
<button ng-click="file(2)">colorred</button>
  {{color}}
  </body>
```